# Chrome Developer Tools: Best resource for learning advanced features?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I casually use Chrome developer tools for debugging AJAX & JavaScript. Mostly that means the console to check on element/variable/method state, occasionally 'network' tab to debug issues fed through ajax, very occasionally break points in debugger if I can't hunt down a JS bug.

But any time a dedicated front-end developer (I'm back end) uses the same tools in front of me, they use these nifty & abstract little features that always leave me thinking "damn, why didn't I know about that"?

...So, the question is: Any suggestions for resources that provide a thorough & more advanced explanation of google chrome devtools?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Addy Osmani did an excellent series on the chrome dev tools, [you can find some of it here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/tag/devtools/). I think that if you read it (and watch the videos), I've found them very useful, if you read them, you're pretty much covered. I included some additional useful resources.

**Addy Osmani Tutorials and videos:**

- [Easy memory profiling using the chrome dev tools](http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/)
- [Visually re-engineering css for faster paint times](http://addyosmani.com/blog/devtools-visually-re-engineering-css-for-faster-paint-times/)
- [The Breakpoint - Chrome dev tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktwJ-EDiZoU)  (Youtube video)
- [The Breakpoint Ep2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPXeWjWp-8Y)  (Youtube video with Paul Irish)
- [The Breakpoint Ep3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HijZNR6kc9A)  (Youtube video, source maps)
- [Chrome devtools course by TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/chrome-developer-tools) (subscription required)

**Official**:

- [Developer tools official guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) by Google
- [Google video tutorials on the developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/videos#google_io_2012) by Google
- [Profiling JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling) by Google

**Other:**

- [Nettuts series](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/chrome-dev-tools-markup-and-style/) , fairly basic but nicely put.
- [A re-introduction to the dev tools](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) by Paul Irish
- [Smashing Magazine also did an article on profiling](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/), but it's fairly basic compared to the Addy Osmani stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another basic one from Code School, including some tasks after each lesson to practice: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/

Comment: That's a good one! I completely forgot about it, it goes into the absolute basics :)

Comment: Here it seems there is another one:
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools  , where intro video is presented by Paul Irish, though the professor is Gregg Pollack. Though the chapters names are different, I am guessing it is the same course...

Answer (score 1):

I've found this Google Chrome Devtools cheatsheet very useful: http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/. Also, [this](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/) interactive course teaches you how to master Chrome DevTools.