# Profiling javascript in visual studio crashes ie

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am trying to instrument a javascript application, however when I try to attach the profiler that comes with visual studio it crashes IE every time. Since I am not likely to get this working through visual studio, does anybody know a good inexpensive profiler that works in asp.net environment with javascript and mvc. I am mainly trying to profile the javascript atm, but might later profile controller and business/service/DAL layer as well, it would be nice if it integrate with visual studio but not a requirement. What I am looking for is a way to locate functions or specific lines of code that takes a long time to execute, hot code.

Comment: Does it have to be in IE? Would a Chrome or Firefox profiler be OK? Also, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed ?

Comment: Firefox or chrome would be fine too, btw the error I get is : "Unhandled exception at 0x77e715de (ntdll.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x06265da8."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752622/chrome-developer-tools-best-resource-for-learning-advanced-features/16752638#16752638