# Profile specific animation CPU

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cpu

**The situation & problem**
I have multiple animations (css and javascript/jQuery) in my site and sometimes it makes my site stutter.

**My question**
How can I see how much cpu a specific animation (both CSS, JavaScript and jQuery) uses in runtime and execution time

I know how I can see the entire site CPU usage but not for a specific animation.

Comment: Did you look at Chrome DevTools ? See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16752638/827168 for more info

Comment: @pomeh Yes I did, but I can't see which CSS animation is using a lot CPU

Comment: I tried this earlier, but then moved on and profiled the website by disabling two of the three animations, three times.

Comment: @Nick ok, indeed tracking CPU usage on CSS animation and tracking CPU usage on JavaScript animation doesn't require the same tooling I guess. Maybe you should update your question with a "what did I do/tried" section :)

Comment: CSS Animations use GPU cycles, not CPU cycles.  A regular JavaScript profiler should give you execution time and CPU usage, but since there's a completely different mechanism at work for CSS animations, these profilers aren't what you need.  The whole point of CSS animations is that they're _hardware accelerated_ meaning that the CPU isn't the main driver behind them.

Comment: Do you combine CSS animations/transitions with jQuery transitions (e.g. `animation()` is changing CSS attributes that are transitioned/animated?). Could you please elaborate on how your multiple animations work (clicking a button starts them, they run infintly on startup, input device action triggers them). Are you using `Window.requestAnimationFrame()`? Is it possible to remove/disable some animation or parts of the whole setup to narrow the animations that may cause the problem.

Comment: use the OS task meter; it doesn't care what the cause is or how the work is performed, just how much of it.

Answer (score 2):

Click F12, Go to profiles, click on start. Reload page.

[image]

Wait untill your page reloaded, and click stop.

Click on your profile and see result (Y)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could you console.profile() with Firefox. 
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/02/02/profiling-javascript-with-firebug-console-profile-console-time/

Put `console.profile()` before the function you want to measure and `console.profileEnd()` after the method.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      myFunc = function() {
        var a = [];
      }             

      console.profile();
      myFunc();
      console.profileEnd();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api
Here you find some more methods for debugging.

**Edit:** I've just found another site with useful information for the firebug extension:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.profile

Comment: I gave you the bounty because you came the closest to answering my question.

Comment: Thanks. I just can't find how to check cpu usage of css animations. If I find it I will post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Preface:  This is not a "complete" answer, as such, but rather the  best I could come up within a reasonable amount of time. It seemed a shame to *not* post my results even though they're not a perfect answer...

It also only covers `jQuery.animate`; I did not investigate CSS animations.

---

For jQuery, at least, this is difficult; it's not like the browser "knows" about
a jQuery animation. Effectively, all jQuery does is schedule a function to run *n* times with `setTimeout()`
or `setInterval()`, where each function call moves the element by a few pixels (or changed something else a little bit), giving the illusion of smooth animations.

Your browser would, somehow, have to keep track of which function call belongs
to which animation. Since these are anonymous functions, this is not really
easy... Some sort of special debugging statement could be used, but AFAIK no
browser implements a feature like this.

What we *can* do is measure the number of updates `jQuery.animate` does with the
`step` callback:

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated element.
>   This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the
>   value of the property before it is set.

This will only give you an *approximation*, at best. But perhaps it's good
enough; I've created an example (see below), which gives me these results on my
system:

```
"a: 52 updates; 26 upd/s"
"b: 27 updates; 54 upd/s"
"c: 1080 updates; 360 upd/s"
```

Your system might vary, but suggests that:

- `a` was the cheapest;
- `b` was slightly more exensive, but also actually quite cheap
- `c` is several times more expensive than `a` or `b`.

To check if this is *roughly* accurate, I enabled only *one* animation at a
time, and checked if this corresponds to what Chromium & Firefox developer tools report:

- Chromium: `a` spent 40ms non-idle; Firefox: 2 calls to `n.fx.tick`
- Chromium: `b` spent 40ms non-idle; Firefox: 4 calls to `n.fx.tick`
- Chromium: `c` spent 130ms non-idle; Firefox: 36 calls to `n.fx.tick`

Which is indeed *roughly* accurate, though not entirely.

Will this be useful enough for your application? I have no idea. Maybe, maybe not...

---

---

Test HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animations test</title>
        <style>
            div { width: 200px; height: 100px; position: relative; color: #fff; }
            #test_a { background-color: green; }
            #test_b { background-color: red; }
            #test_c { background-color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test_a"></div>
        <div id="test_b"></div>
        <div id="test_c"></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="anim.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test JS in CoffeeScript:

```
go = ->
    a = b = c = 0

    log = (n, t) ->
        eval "u = #{n}"
        str = "#{n}: #{u} updates; #{parseInt u / t, 10} upd/s"
        $("#test_#{n}").html str
        console.log str

    $('#test_a').animate {left: '500px'},
        duration: 500
        step: -> a += 1
        complete: -> log 'a', .5

    $('#test_b').animate {top: '100px', left: '100px', opacity: 0.3, width: '500px'},
        duration: 200
        step: -> b += 1
        complete: -> log 'b', 2

    $('#test_c').animate {left: '500px', top: '300px', opacity: .75, height: '50px', width: '400px'},
        duration: 3000
        step: -> c += 1
        complete: -> log 'c', 3

$(document).ready -> setTimeout go, 500
```

And the same JS compiled for convenience:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  var go;

  go = function() {
    var a, b, c, log;
    a = b = c = 0;
    log = function(n, t) {
      var str;
      eval("u = " + n);
      str = "" + n + ": " + u + " updates; " + (parseInt(u / t, 10)) + " upd/s";
      $("#test_" + n).html(str);
      return console.log(str);
    };
    $('#test_a').animate({
      left: '500px'
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      step: function() {
        return a += 1;
      },
      complete: function() {
        return log('a', .5);
      }
    });
    return;
    $('#test_b').animate({
      top: '100px',
      left: '100px',
      opacity: 0.3,
      width: '500px'
    }, {
      duration: 200,
      step: function() {
        return b += 1;
      },
      complete: function() {
        return log('b', 2);
      }
    });
    return $('#test_c').animate({
      left: '500px',
      top: '300px',
      opacity: .75,
      height: '50px',
      width: '400px'
    }, {
      duration: 3000,
      step: function() {
        return c += 1;
      },
      complete: function() {
        return log('c', 3);
      }
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return setTimeout(go, 500);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try running a `console.profile()` instance at the start of each jQuery animation and then disable animations one at a time to debug.

You cannot profile CSS animations as far as I know. Only the starting and ending values are accessible via JavaScript.

```js
function AnimateRotate(elem, angle, dur) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  // we use a pseudo object for the animation
  // (starts from `0` to `angle`), you can name it as you want
  $({
    deg: 0
  }).animate({
    deg: angle
  }, {
    duration: dur,
    step: function(now) {
      // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
      // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
      // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
      $elem.css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
      });
    }
  });
}

$('#1').click(function() {
  console.profile('Animation #1');
  $(this).animate({
    'height': '100px',
    'width': '100px'
  }, function() {
    console.profileEnd('Animation #1');
  });
});

$('#2').click(function() {
  console.profile('Animation #2');
  AnimateRotate(this, 3000, 400);
  $(this).animate({
    'height': '300px',
    'width': '300px'
  }, function() {
    console.profileEnd('Animation #2');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 60% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"></div>
<br>
<div id="2"></div>
```